# Manipulate JSON in bash

Tags: bash, json

I have a JSON file I need to update a particular value.

```
{
  "Comment": "comment",
  "test": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "enabled": true,
  "otherStuff": blah,
  "otherStuff2": blah,
  "otherStuff3": blah,
}
```

I would like to change the value of the second "enabled" to false.
With JQ Parser, I can easily retrieve it with *jq '.enabled*', but I'm not sure what's the best way to manipulate the JSON.

The JSON is a respond i get from an API and may change in the future, I cannot rely on the line or value before/after.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

a quick experiment:

```
$ echo '{
  "Comment": "comment",
  "test": {
    "enabled": true
   },
  "enabled": true,
  "otherStuff": "blah",
  "otherStuff2": "blah",
  "otherStuff3": "blah"
}' |
jq '.enabled=false'
```

```
{
  "otherStuff3": "blah",
  "otherStuff2": "blah",
  "otherStuff": "blah",
  "enabled": false,
  "test": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "Comment": "comment"
}
```

Comment: How would you change two keys?

Answer (score 1):

I read the question as "in the shell" and not necessarily as *"using only bash builtins".*

Try [jsawk](https://github.com/micha/jsawk), which allows for manipulation and is scriptable, thought it relies on js as a dependency.

If all you want to do is read a (unique) key from the JSON response, you could (adapted from [Brendan OConnor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6852427/114900)):

```
curl <destination> | grep -Po '"keyname":.*?[^\\]",'`
```